# How to open an editor directly from rspec output within the console?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, debugging, rspec2, sublimetext

In order to speed up development and debug process

```
Given I have some rspec output in my console with file path and line numbers
When I click on the file name and line number within the console
Then I want my editor to open and scroll the cursor to the specified line
```

I'm currently using Sublime-Text-2 with Ubuntu 11.10 and running Rspec2's autotest feature.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the editor, if the editor even supports it at all.  You'd have to write some python for SublimeText2.  Also, "clicking" something in the console doesn't make sense... a console is a text-only terminal.

Comment: Thanks d11wtq but the http links open up a browser so that last statement definitely isn't quiet correct. I do realise the links will need to be something like subline::file//blah or whatever but I dont even know how I can get rspec to generate those kind of links.

Comment: I don't use rspec but I _think_ you can define custom `Formatter` classes. See https://github.com/shingara/rspec-formatter for an example. You could then output the file:line paths as uris, _then_ try to register a handler for that uri scheme which takes the url and calls the `subl` command with appropriate args

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should be able to do this with the funcionality built into the sublime text's build system, by piggybacking on the error capturing functionality. although I'm not 100% sure if the clicking is supported.

There is some documentation [here](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html) and [here](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/core/build_systems.html) about setting them up. If you dig around in the default packages supplied with sublime text should be be able to find some more examples.

You'll want to make a build system that spawns off your rspec cmd. In the build configuration, you'll want to pay special attention to the the `"file_regex"` key. This will let you define a regex to capture the error output of the `cmd`.

Here is what the documentation says about it:

The file_regex option uses a Perl-style regular expression to capture up to four fields of error information from the build program’s output, namely: file name, line number, column number and error message. Use groups in the pattern to capture this information. The file name field and the line number field are required.

> When error information is captured, you can navigate to error
>   instances in your project’s files with F4 and Shift+F4. If available,
>   the captured error message will be displayed in the status bar.

Also you might be able to get some more traction over at the [sublimetext forums](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/) about the particulars.

Answer (score 0):

I am a litte late to the party ... but it might be helpful for people who are still looking for this.

[Sublime Text 2 - RSpec HTML Output](https://gist.github.com/BYTEPOETS/4943232)